# ggarrange() for ggplots overlap annotate() text

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm having a problem with plots using `ggarrange()` from `egg` library. When a I visualize every single plot (using RStudio), they are perfect. However, when I merged three plots in one single plot, the relative size of each grid change with respect to the size of every plot, and also, annotated texts get overlap one to another, and relative sizes of fonts change. It seems to be more a problem of visualization than of code, but I don't know.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)

data <-
  structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
                                       .Label = c("A","B", "C", "D"),
                                       class = "factor"),
                 Var1 = c(10L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 20L, 20L, 26L, 24L, 17L),
                 Var2 = c(2.5, 2.6, 2.3, 2.8, 2.9, 1.5, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 3.2, 3.5, 3.3, 3.2, 3.1),
                 Var3 = c(1.1,1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 0.9, 0.85, 0.9, 0.8, 0.85)),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c(NA, -20L))

figura2a <-
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) +
  geom_point(aes(
    color = Treatment,
    shape = Treatment,
    size = 2.5
  )) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',
              colour = "black",
              se = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(
    "lightsteelblue4",
    "salmon",
    "purple3",
    "royalblue2",
    "seagreen3"
  )) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 25, 18, 17)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22)
  ) +
  theme(text = element_text(
    size = 22,
    family = "Arial",
    color = "black"
  )) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  scale_size(guide = 'none') +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  xlab("Var2") +
  ylab("Var1") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 3,
    y = 4,
    label = "R^2 == 0.8639",
    parse = TRUE,
    color = "black",
    size = 5
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 3,
    y = 5.5,
    label = "p < 0.001",
    color = "black",
    size = 5.5,
    fontface = 'italic',
    check_overlap = TRUE
  )
figura2a
```

[image]

```r
figura2b <-
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Var3, y = Var1)) +
  geom_point(aes(
    color = Treatment,
    shape = Treatment,
    size = 2.5
  )) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',
              colour = "black",
              se = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(
    "lightsteelblue4",
    "salmon",
    "purple3",
    "royalblue2",
    "seagreen3"
  )) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15, 16, 25, 18, 17)) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 22)
  ) +
  theme(text = element_text(
    size = 22,
    family = "Arial",
    color = "black"
  )) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "black"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 20)) +
  scale_size(guide = 'none') +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  xlab("Var3") +
  ylab("Var1") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 1.2,
    y = 22,
    label = "R^2 == 0.8252",
    parse = TRUE,
    color = "black",
    size = 5
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = 1.2,
    y = 20,
    label = "p < 0.001",
    color = "black",
    size = 5.5,
    fontface = 'italic'
  )
figura2b
```

[image]

```r
figura2 <- ggarrange(figura2a, figura2b, ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` and paste it here. Also, edit your question and put the data and the code there using proper formatting. You may also read about `reprex` library (part of `tidyverse`) - it's very handy to produce reproducible examples.

Comment: I have tried to improve my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I agree it's a pain to set a relative position of annotation. If you only need the final plot (`figura2`) then you may play with `height` and `width` ratio in `ggsave()` and `x` and `y` in `annotate()` to get the right ratio between the plots so that the annotations are placed right. I'd try something like `figura2 <- (figura2a, figura2b, ncol = 1, nrow = 2) + ggsave('figura2.png', width = 12, height = 8)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found a bit intuitive how to find the right width and height, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

It is more a problem of visualization than of code，I got the same problem using ggarrange,when scaling the plot,the relative size and position got change,maybe you can increase the margin between two overlapped items in ggplot() using theme() function before using ggarrange:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Var3, y = Var1))+
#adjust y label positions
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin (r = 10)),
#change the plot margins
plot.margin = margin(l = 15,r=10))
```